# Android setting an Icon for notifies

Tags: java, android, icons

I'm trying to set an icon image (.bmp) on my `android app` but for some reason it is giving me error at      `notifyObj.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(R.drawable.icon, NOTIFY_ME_ID));`

It is like .icon is of type int but it is an image type bmp.

```
public void triggerNotification(View v) {
//Notification notifyObj=new Notification(R.drawable.whatsappicon2,      "Notification message!",System.currentTimeMillis());
  Context context = getApplicationContext();   
    PendingIntent i=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, NotifyActivity.class), 0);
    Notification.Builder notifyObj = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("content title")
    .setContentText("http://android-er.blogspot.com/")
    .setTicker("Notification!")
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setContentIntent(i)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
    .setAutoCancel(false)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.whatsappicon2)
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
 Notification mynotification1 = notifyObj.getNotification();
 notifyObj.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(R.drawable.icon, NOTIFY_ME_ID));   
notifyObj.setNumber(++countmsg);
countconv=convnum(countmsg);

notifyMgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, mynotification1);
}
```

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's a great way of converting resource images into Android Bitmaps:

```
Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.large_icon);
notBuilder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
```